# How to use ggplot2 facet colors and shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Maybe, I missed something in the ggplot grammar. The following 3 facets can be plotted without any error. Unfortuantely, the facet plots mixed up colors and shapes. The right hand column should show blue markers only, while the center one should have green markers.

```
data1
num     delay claim supply project
1 -236.347551  3000    DIF   site1
2   65.132011  5000    Hoc   site2
3   61.401260  5000    Hoc   site2
4   96.902894   500    Hoc   site2
..
base04 <- ggplot(data1, aes(num, delay, size=claim, color=supply, shape=project))
base04 + geom_point() + facet_grid( . ~ supply ) 
base04 + geom_point() + facet_grid( project ~ . )
base04 + geom_point() + facet_grid( project ~ supply )
```

[image: 2D facet plot]

Many thanks for your ideas ..

Comment: I can't replicate the error you are describing with the data you provided. I'm assuming those are erroneous "+" marks at the end of the lines? Because you can't really add facets together.

Comment: If you are faceting by a variable you don't need to have it in the `aes()` as well (although you can if you wish).  Try leaving `project` and/or `supply` out of the `aes` until you get the combination of colours and shapes that you want.

Comment: MrFlick. You are correct .. my mistake. The "+" should be there, but even then the colors and shapes are not correct.

Comment: Andrew:I already took color=supply and shape=project out of the ggplot and tried base04 + geom_point( aes(color=var4, shape=project) ) +
  facet_grid( . ~ supply ). It shows the same mismatch.

Comment: I don't think I can see the mismatch you are talking about, at least in the example dataset you gave.  Can you link to an image of the plot you see the mismatch in?

Comment: tja, how to attach an the jpeg to the comment line ..